# Java socket communication

Tags: java, sockets

I have a problem with my program.
For explain it I would use an example:

I have two programs, A and B.
A controls B with sockets, A have the client and B the server.

The A client code:

```
package clientTimer;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
        private String action;
        private String ip;

        public Client(String action,String ip) {
                this.action=action;
                this.ip=ip;
                String serverName = "server";
                int port = 9999;
                try {
                        Socket client = new Socket(ip, port);
                        OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
                        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
                        out.writeUTF(action);
                        InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
                        DataInputStream in =new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
                        new Countdown(in.readUTF(),true);
                        client.close();
                }catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

The B server code:

```
package serverTimer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketException;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server extends Thread {
   private String correct;

   public Server() {
       run();
   }


   public void run() {
           correct="q";
         try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9999);
            while(true) {
              Socket server = serverSocket.accept();
              DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream());
              new Viewer(in.readUTF());
              DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());
              if (correct.length()==5) {
                  out.writeUTF(correct);
              } else {
                  out.writeUTF("a");
              }
              server.close();
           }
         }catch(SocketTimeoutException s) {
            System.out.println("Socket timed out!");
         }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
   }
}
```

As you can see, the client send and receive a string, the same for the server.
My problem is: the server must send a toString() method (in the code the string is called "correct") of an object in the same package to client.
I don't know how I can do it.
The object with the toString method is initialized in another file of the package (the Viewer(String)).

Thanks.

edit:
I'm sorry, is a little bit difficult for me explain it.
In a simple scheme what I need is:
A says "do something" to -> B says "I do that" to -> A
or
A outputstream-> B inputstream - B outputstream -> A inputstream.
A have problems with the B outputstream -> A inputstream.
The outputstream must send a string product by a toString() method of another class (in the B package).

The program is a timer controlled remotely, the A package have the controller and the B package have the viewer.
I send the A commands to B via socket, but I need that B "occasionally" send to A a "report" with the current time.

I can't write all the program here, it's too "big".
If you want I can send you an email with all the file.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "server must send toString() method", communication consists of data.

Comment: Don't save code at other services, copy the relevant parts into your question, please.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. What I can add to the discussion, however, is that when I need to pass objects over sockets I use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` using serializable objects. Another option would be RMI, but again, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you can take all the application-specific stuff out, and boil the question down to a simple example of what you're trying to do, it'd be very helpful.  (As well as make it easy to show your code here locally instead of on pastebin.

Comment: Sounds like sending and receiving is not the problem. You are saying that the server does not have access to some Object, yet it wants to send data about that object. Also, you talk about "packages" but why would a class not have access to an Object just because that object is in a different package?

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I've correct the post with some corrections.
@Darius X I think you hit the problem thank you; no I'm sure that the second class is in the same package. If you want I can put in the post the other class.

Comment: it sounds like you need to change your question quite a bit, or create a new one. No point adding more code... just show the relevant parts of your code, to illustrate the issue.